# Объединить сервера и выполнить команду одновременно SSH C#

Tags: c#, ssh

У меня есть 3 сервера (Dediceted Server).

Я подключаюсь к ним с помощью SSH C#.

Мне надо выполнить одну команду на всех трех серверах одновременно, но они выполняются по очереди, сначала зайдет на первый сервер, выполнит команду, потом на второй, также выполнит команду, и потом заходит на последний сервер.

---

```
using (var client1 = new SshClient("96.102.49.253", "root "Пароль"))
{

    client1.Connect();
    client1.RunCommand("команда");
}
```

Что то типа этого, только тут 1 сервер, а мне надо 3, можно ли как то их объединить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Про удаление: StackOverflow так не работает. Ваш вопрос и ответы на него должны остаться здесь для будущих читателей (которых будут сотни или тысячи). Вся суть в том, чтобы накапливать базу готовых решений.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```
var params = new List<Param>();
params.Add(new Param{IP = "", Login = "", Password = ""});
... заполняем так или иначе лист params данными, под которыми надо подключаться
Parallel.ForEach(params,
    v =>
    {
        using (var client1 = new SshClient(v.IP, v.Login, v.Password)) 
        {
            client1.Connect();
            client1.RunCommand("команда");
        }
    });

class Param
{
  public string IP { get; set;}

  public string Login { get; set;}

  public string Password { get; set;}

}
```

Comment: Недопустимый элемент "params" в выражении.
Мне надо сделать чтоб это ещё было при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Всё разобрался, спасибо :)